# Install PostgreSQL on Linux, I met the error: "-bash: /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb: Permission denied", Why?

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos8

My Cloud OS is OpenEuler, Just like CentOS.
I want to install postgresql14.2, I do just like below:

```
[root@ecs ~]# dnf -y update
[root@ecs ~]# dnf install -y bc tmux readline-devel zlib zlib-devel tar vim
[root@ecs ~]# groupadd postgres
[root@ecs ~]# useradd -g postgres postgres
[root@ecs ~]# passwd postgres
[root@ecs ~]# wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v14.2/postgresql-14.2.tar.gz
[root@ecs ~]# tar -xzvf postgresql-14.2.tar.gz
[root@ecs ~]# cd postgresql-14.2
[root@ecs ~]# ./configure 
[root@ecs ~]# make 
[root@ecs ~]# make install 
[root@ecs ~]# mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data 
[root@ecs ~]# chown -R postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
[root@ecs ~]# su - postgres
[postgres@ecs ~]$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

When I run the command:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

I meet the error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb: Permission denied
```

I don't know how to deal with this kind of error,
Please give me some advice.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this trouble, use:

```
chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql -R
```

replace

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
```